# 'Send is not a member of System.Net.Mail.Mailmessage" ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm receiving the noted error. I clearly don't know what I'm doing here. What library should i use? I'm getting the error on the objMail.Send() line. The code I received was originally snagged from .asp I need to use the CDONTS to send via exchange I believe, I can't use any external servers such as gmail etc... I'm not sure I completely understand this but thought I would give it a whirl. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
  <%@ Import Namespace="System.Net.Mail" %>

 <%


 ' declare variables
 Dim EmailFrom
 Dim EmailTo
 Dim Subject
 Dim Name
 Dim LastName

 ' get posted data into variables
 EmailFrom = "test@test.com"
 EmailTo = "gfuller@unum.com"
 Subject = "OMAR adhoc"
 Name = Trim(Request.Form("Name")) 
 LastName = Trim(Request.Form("LastName")) 

 ' validation
 Dim validationOK
 validationOK=true
 If (validationOK=false) Then Response.Redirect("error.htm?" & EmailFrom)

 ' prepare email body text
 Dim Body
 Body = Body & "Name: " & Name & VbCrLf
 Body = Body & "LastName: " & LastName & VbCrLf

 ' send email 
 Dim objMail As MailMessage = Server.CreateObject("CDONTS.NewMail")
 'mail = Server.CreateObject("CDONTS.NewMail")
 objMail.To.Add(EmailTo)
 'objMail.To = EmailTo
 objMail.From = EmailFrom
 objMail.Subject = Subject
 objMail.Body = Body
 objMail.Send()
 ' redirect to success page 
 Response.Redirect("ok.htm?" & EmailFrom)
 %>
```

Answer (score 2):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.aspx

Look at that. It's done by the SMTPClient (which takes the message as a parameter), not by the Message itself.

So, just set up a SMTPClient object appropriately and you should be able to call the .Send(MailMessage) method on that object with your 'objMail' message as the parameter.

Here's a link to the actual SMTPClient in VB that you want - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx , with details on how to set it up towards the bottom.